# What's the best way to remove event listener on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery `.off()` API can only remove the event that was added by using its own `on`(or `bind` in jQuery) method, many third-party plugins may add events using pure javascript and because of browser compatibility issues, is there any **single line of code** that can do this stuff more easily?

Comment: Depends too much on how the event was added. It may just as well be a listener on the whole document that checks for a matching selector upon receiving the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the event handler was added with `.addEventListener()`, then the only way to remove it is with `.removeEventListener()` and this means that you need to know the handler function too in order to use `.removeEventListener()` so if an anonymous function was used as the handler, then there is no way to remove the event listener.

In some circumstances, a heavy handed way to clear all event listeners off a DOM element is to replace it with a new element of the same type (perhaps preserving child elements while doing so).  This is obviously a blunt instrument because it will clear all state that was associated with the prior DOM element.

Comment: Thank you, remove events with anonymous function is a little bit troublesome I think.

Answer (score 1):

If the event is added by `jQuery.on()`, you can remove it with `jQuery.off()`.

If the event is added by `jQuery.bind()`, you can remove it with `jQuery.unbind()`.

If the event is added by pure `.addEventListener()` in pure javascript , you can remove it with `.removeEventListener()` .

Answer (score 0):

If event is added by plugin, so you won't be knowing the method how event was added, so to make sure that events are removed, you need to clear the DOM element and create a new element identical to the one that is deleted...